# Trying to change the img src from an array on click using react

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

Im trying to change the img src getting the src from and array based on the direction of arrow that is clicked in react.js.

So for example I have an array when a user clicks on the right arrow it will change the img src forward and if she clicks backs it will go back the prev image

here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

var i = 0;
var blogPostImages = ['./img/placeholder.jpg', './img/placeholderB.jpg', './img/placeholderC.png'];

export default class HomePage extends Component {

    changeBlogPicForwards() {
        if (i == blogPostImages.length - 1) {
             i = 0; 
          } else {
            i = i + 1; 
        }
        let blogPostImages = blogPostImages[i];
    }

    changeBlogPicBackwards() {
        if (i == 0) {
            i = blogPostImages.length - 1; 
        } else {
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }

    render() {
        var blogCurrentPic = this.state.blogPostImages[i];

        return (

            <div>


     <div className="top-section-actions">
                    <div className="image-holder">
                        <img className="blog-pictures" src={blogPostImages}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="blog-name">
                        <div className="left-arrow-action arrow-icons">
                            <i onClick={(e) => this.changeBlogPicForwards(e)} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="right-arrow-action arrow-icons">
                            <i onClick={(e) => this.changeBlogPicBackwards(e)} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that the `src` attribute of your image should be `blogCurrentPic`, not `blogPostImages`.

Comment: what is the error u r getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to maintain `i` in the state so that you can signal react to re-render the page when the state changes using `setState`. Also, the src should be `blogCurrentPic`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = { index : 0 };
        this.blogPostImages = ['./img/placeholder.jpg', './img/placeholderB.jpg', './img/placeholderC.png'];
    }

    changeBlogPicForwards() {
        let i = this.state.index;
        if (i == this.blogPostImages.length - 1) {
            i = 0; 
        } else {
            i = i + 1; 
        }
        this.setState({index: i});
    }

    changeBlogPicBackwards() {
        let i = this.state.index;
        if (i == 0) {
            i = this.blogPostImages.length - 1; 
        } else {
            i = i - 1;
        }
        this.setState({index: i});
    }

    render() {
        var blogCurrentPic = this.blogPostImages[this.state.index];

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="top-section-actions">
                    <div className="image-holder">
                        <img className="blog-pictures" src={blogCurrentPic}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="blog-name">
                        <div className="left-arrow-action arrow-icons">
                            <i onClick={(e) => this.changeBlogPicForwards(e)} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div className="right-arrow-action arrow-icons">
                            <i onClick={(e) => this.changeBlogPicBackwards(e)} className="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setState({'i':i})`to refresh your state, setState will make component reRender. it will solve your question